# GoogleAnalyticsTracker: Store full. Not storing last event

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, google-analytics-api

I keep hitting this error message in Logcat:

```
GoogleAnalyticsTracker: Store full. Not storing last event.
```

I've tried many different things yet I still keep getting the error. I am using EasyTracker but manually track pageviews using:

```
@Override
public void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    try {
        EasyTracker.getTracker().trackPageView("Category Activity");
        //Tried adding the below line as well - didn't help
        //EasyTracker.getTracker().dispatch();
    }
    catch (NullPointerException e) {

    }
}
```

I'm not sure what else I can do.

Comment: possible duplicate of [GoogleAnalyticsTracker Store full](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13503335/googleanalyticstracker-store-full)