# GoogleAnalyticsTracker Store full

Tags: android, google-analytics-api

I've seen a couple of similar posts on this site, but neither one had any response so I'm going to post my issue.

I'm getting the following warnings from GoogleAnalyticsTracker: Store full.  Not storing last event.

I'm using GoogleAnalyticsTracker in my Android app to store analytics.  It all executes fine, except for the above warnings, however no data seems to be getting to Google Analytics since every time I check it there's nothing there.

```
GoogleAnalyticsTracker tracker;
tracker = GoogleAnalyticsTracker.getInstance();
tracker.startNewSession(GA_ID , this);

// i've got a bunch of these throughout my activity
tracker.trackEvent("BTN CLICK", "myactivity", "some info",n);
```

Can anyone from Google provide some info on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to manually call dispatch to push stored events or better star with autamatic dispatch with giving an interval.

Change it to this, and your events will pushed to analytics every 10 seconds.
    tracker.startNewSession(GA_ID , 10, this);

Answer (score 0):

It's because you didn't set the dispatch interval in startNewSession method. You can either set it in above method or do it manually by `tracker.dispatch()` method.